# What is the 55/3 Monsoon Formula?

Tags: monsoon

I came across an [obituary](http://tucsoncitizen.com/morgue2/2003/09/20/20997-funeral-notices/) for a distant cousin which mentions that he was a state climatologist who developed the "55/3 monsoon formula."

> KANGIESER, Paul Carl, 1923 – 2003 Passed away September 15, 2003 after a long battle with cancer. Born in Topeka, lived in LA as a child. Served in the U.S. Army for four years in WWII. **As state Climatologist of AZ he developed the 55/3 monsoon formula.**

I searched Google and couldn't find any formulas related to monsoons known as the "55/3 formula", but I did find [this news article](https://www.azfamily.com/weather/phoenix_weather_blog/monsoon-season-the-dew-point-dilemma/article_45060ef3-873f-5128-a7dd-fea3b7a545f6.html):

> In 2008, The National Weather Service in Phoenix decided to make a big change. For decades, the monsoon was said to have started after **three** consecutive days with a dew point of **55** degrees of higher.

What is the 55/3 monsoon formula?

Comment: I have no familiarity with that, nor much focus on monsoon rainfall... but sounds like a reasonable rule of thumb out there... so that would make sense to be it, what you found.

Comment: Couldn't find anything about a monsoon formula, but he did have some [journal articles back in the day](https://journals.ametsoc.org/action/doSearch?AllField=kangieser&pageSize=20&startPage=1).

Comment: Another ref on slide 22 in this [powerpoint](http://www.atmo.arizona.edu/~swhs/Presentations/FriAM2/J_Skindlov_SW4HYMET_True_Monsoon_Sep_2007_v3.ppt)

Comment: Seems an answer to me @mkennedy, as it ties the formula into Kangieser, and gives more thorough explanation of what applies.  Doesn't officially call it the 55/3 formula, but goes into enough detail.  Not sure anyone is going to find better, and would be tough to find forecasters around from the era to help verify.

Comment: @mkennedy, I agree that the reference on slide 22 seems to be the fullest explanation available. If you make that an answer I would accept it.